# Easy 2d graph animation software

Tags: animation, graph, theory, contract

I would like to animate a graph theory algorithm, which contains some edge contractions. It would be nice to animate these contractions, thus the viewer can follow these changes in the topology. Is there any free software for this simple task? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about SVG? You could use a JS library such as Snap to animate it. Sounds easy enough for me, if you can live with the fact that all shapes are directly in the file.